# Ошибка при загрузки App Bundle Google Play

Tags: unity3d, google-play, unity3d-android

При загрузки игры в Google play выдаёт следующую ошибку:
Вы загрузили APK-файл или набор Android App Bundle с объектом activity, псевдонимом объекта, сервисом или широковещательным приемником с фильтром intent, но без набора свойств android:exported. Этот файл нельзя установить на устройство с версией Android 12 или выше. Чтобы узнать больше, перейдите на developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.

В юнити обновил пакети. В Android Manifest добавил строку android:exported="true". Однако ошибка осталась. Версия юнити 2020.3.41f1

Comment: Куда вы добавили строку? Если ошибка осталась то вероятно не туда добавили

Comment: В activity '<activity android:name="...." android:label="...." android:exported="true">'